# unable to hide label and gridview from java script in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, gridview

I would like to hide *label* and *grid view* in *javascript*.
I had succeed to hide *images* and *checkboxes* but not yet *label* and *grid view*.
How to do it using javascript?

**javascript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function txtOnKeyPress(txt1)
         {
            if (txt1 != 'undefined') 
            {
             document.getElementById("GVPaymentDetails").style.display='none';
             document.getElementById('LblValidReg').style.display='none';

            }
         }
    </script>
```

**aspx code**

```
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtRegno" runat="server"  AutoPostBack="false"
            MaxLength="10"  onkeydown="txtOnKeyPress(this);"></asp:TextBox>



 <asp:GridView ID="GVPaymentDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            BackColor="White" BorderColor="#336666" BorderStyle="Double" BorderWidth="3px" 
            CellPadding="4" GridLines="Horizontal" EmptyDataText="No Records Found">
            <RowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Enquiry id" DataField="EnquiryId" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Reg Number" DataField="RegistrationNumber" />
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="Name" DataField="Name" />
            </Columns>
            <FooterStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#333333" />
            <PagerStyle BackColor="#336666" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#339966" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="#336666" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:GridView>

 <asp:Label ID="LblValidReg" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Why don't you wrap them in a `div` or `asp:Panel` and hide that? Then you're only dealing with one object instead of two.

Comment: but im unable to hide any of them @HugoYates

Comment: i have kept label  in div with this id - divValidReg@HugoYates

Comment: document.getElementById('divValidReg').style.display = "none";

not working

Comment: Check both control id using browser console. Generated id of both controls may be different so you can not access in java script. use clientId Mode="static" in both controls.

Answer (score 1):

The ID that you see in the .aspx markup is not the ID that ends up on the client-side page. ASP.NET generates a bunch of stuff in place of this ID. Options you have:

1. If your javascript is in the same .aspx file, you can embed client side ID into it, like this:

   ```
   document.getElementById("<%= GVPaymentDetails.ClientID %>").style.display='none';
   ```
2. If you can give 100% guarantee that there is no other control on the page with the same ID, use static ID mode, which will force ASP.NET to render the exactly same ID on the client side:

   ```
   <asp:GridView ID="GVPaymentDetails" ClientIDMode="Static"
   ```

   In that case your code will work as is:

   ```
   document.getElementById("GVPaymentDetails").style.display='none';
   ```

Also as already pointed out in the comments, it will make your live easier to wrap these controls in some kind of a container like Panel or just a div.

**Update**

In fact if you just put a simple div around them you won't need any of the trickery above:

```
<div id="GridViewContainerDiv">
    <asp:GridView ID="GVPaymentDetails" ...
    <asp:Label ID="LblValidReg" ...
</div>

document.getElementById("GridViewContainerDiv").style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function txtOnKeyPress(txt1)
     {
        if (txt1 != 'undefined') 
        {
         document.getElementById("<%= GVPaymentDetails.ClientId%>").style.display='none';
         document.getElementById('<%= LblValidReg.ClientId%>').style.display='none';

        }
     }
</script>
```

OR

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVPaymentDetails" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ClientIdMode="static" 


<asp:Label ID="LblValidReg" ClientIdMode="Static" runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Comment: Doesn't it look exactly the same as the other answer, only appearing later?

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$("#<%=GVPaymentDetails.ClientID %>").css('display','none');
$("#<%=LblValidReg.ClientID %>").css('display','none');
```

Insted Of

```
 document.getElementById("<%= GVPaymentDetails.ClientId%>").style.display='none';
 document.getElementById('<%= LblValidReg.ClientId%>').style.display='none';
```

Comment: This assumes jquery, which OP might not be using. Besides, what's wrong with `style.display='none'`?

Comment: style.display='none' is ok but,It's may be use Master page i doubt on document.getElementById

Comment: Your code works internally exactly the same as document.getElementById. In fact, it calls it. And this is javascript, there are no master/content pages here, at least in ASP.NET sense

Comment: friends. i found y its not displaying. if any of the element null . it breaks the code . and further not moving

kindly tell how to check null. if null also it should go into next statement